# C++ Pthreads - Multithreading slower than single-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, pthreads, posix

I am developing a C++ application, using pthreads library. Every thread in the program accesses a common unordered_map. The program runs slower with 4 threads than 1. I commented all the code in thread, and left only the part that tokenizes a string. Still the single-threading execution is faster, so I came to the conclusion that the map wasn't the problem. 
After that I printed to the screen the threads' Ids, and they seemed to execute sequentially.

In the function that calls the threads, I have a while loop, which creates threads in an array, which size is the number of threads (let's say 'tn'). And every time tn threads are created, I execute a for loop to join them. (pthread_join). While runs many times(not only 4).

What may be wrong?

Comment: Are you using a mutex to access the map?

Comment: My magic 8-ball says the error is on line 42. [i.e., impossible to even guess based on a high-level description of part of what the code may or may not do.]

Comment: How much slower? Are you using an architecture that can benefit from multiple threads?

Comment: @user3309479 you should mention that in the question. I'ts relevant.

Comment: but when I remove the critical section, and keep only the tokenizing, it is still slower. Or is the tokenizing trivial?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running a small trivial program this tends to be the case because the work to start the threads, schedule priority, run, context switch, then sync could actually take more time then running it as a single process.

The point here is that when dealing with trivial problems it can run slower. BUT another factor might be how many cores you actually have in your CPU.

Comment: Every thread takes as a parameter a very big text. It tokenizes it and add its words to a map. The thread creates a temporary map. And then when it finishes tokenize it adds the temp map to the common map. I have 4 cores. The time is multiplied by ~4. But I have tried to remove the code about the map and keep only the tokenize.. but still

Comment: @user3309479 you forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: @user2079303: And that map has to be synchronized with a mutex so that only one thread at a time can use it. Therefore, your code is serialized and the threads don't help you.

Comment: yes, i am using a mutex when i write to the common map.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a multitthreaded program, each thread will be processed sequentially according to the given CPU clock.

You will only have true multithreading if you have multiple cores. And in such scenario the only multithreading will be 1 thread /core.

Now, given the fact that you (most likely) have both threads on one core, try to keep in mind the overhead generated to the CPU for :

- allocating different clock time for each thread
- synchronizing thread accesses to various internal CPU operations
- other thread priority operations

So in other words, for a simple application, multithreading is actually a downgrade in terms of performance.

Multithreading comes in handy when you need a asynchronous operation (meaning you don't want to wait for a rezult, such as loading an image from an url or streaming geomtery from HDD which is slower then ram) .

In such scenarios, applying multithreading will lead to better user experience, because your program won't hung up when a slow operation occurrs.

Comment: This answer seems a bit outdated to me. Most systems these days have multiple cores.

Comment: You can consider this. But , if you have more threads then number of cores, you're going to bump into the same issue. Even more, most OSs run multiple processes , each with it's own threading system. Inevitably you will run into multiple threads on one CPU problem, which leads to CPU clock allocation for each thread according to priority.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's difficult to tell for sure, but there could be a number of issues.

Your threads might not be doing enough work to justify their creation. Creating and running threads is expensive, so if your workload is too small, they won't pay for themselves.

Execution time could be spent mostly doing memory accesses on the map, in which case mutually excluding the threads means that you aren't really doing much parallel work in practice (Amdahl's Law).

Answer (score 0):

If most of your code is running under a mutex that it will run serially and not in parllel